# How to patch a line of code in a DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I've got a .Net dll that misses a line of code. I would like to patch that DLL, but I don't have the source code. How would I go about? Does anyone know a **quick way** of patching something like this?

Comment: I'm assuming it is from a 3rd party vendor and you don't have the original source code?

Comment: Yes... and it is not obfuscated. I need to add one extra condition to an `if`. It is fixed in their new version, but I can't upgrade to a new version.

Comment: Good luck. Don't think it is possible. The DLL could even be signed with a code certificate and then you would invalidate it completely after patching.

Comment: @0A0D DLL is not signed.

Comment: You're not allowed to upgrade to the new version, but you _are_ allowed to patch? Interesting.

Comment: @John No I can upgrade, but I don't have the time to test their new version properly, but this bug is bugging my client a lot.

Comment: @Kees: you don't have time to test the new version, but you _do_ have time to test your patch, which you assume will only affect the single line of code? I'd tell your client to wait for the upgrade.

Comment: @John: Jep. And the client has been told... so reverse engineering the dll seems to be the best option.

Comment: @Kees, we've all been there. Version X has 1 small bug and version Y fixes it but introduces 100 new features, too, so you don't want to upgrade. But what John is saying is that trying to fix this one bug without seeing the entire source might break everything else. Its possible that portions of the code rely on this bug so fixing it for you might break it elsewhere.

Comment: @Kees: I recommend you not waste your time.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853672/c-monkey-patching-is-it-possible/2861376#2861376 .  Has a performance cost.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the [Reflexil](http://sebastien.lebreton.free.fr/reflexil/) plugin for [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1), modifying a small part of a DLL is **quick and easy**.  I've used this on a handful of occasions to change a line or two in a deployed dll, usually to disable some behavior that's the result of a condition (and no, not cracking an app, legitimate uses on our own code to avoid the weight of a full deploy).

Comment: If you have the source code, and it is easier to patch the dll than it is to fix the bug in the code and recompile, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Nick: must've been a Freudian slip since I refuse to support Reflector and RedGate after they killed Reflector v6.

Comment: @Lasse: That's a very optimistic point of view that is often untrue when faced with real circumstances.

Comment: I'll try that! Hopefully it works with the trial version as well!

Comment: @qes Well, that is my opinion, I've never had to patch some program *I've* made that I also have the source code to by patching the resulting binary, it has *always* been easier to just fix the bug in the code and recompile. So yes, in my opinion you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Lasse: Situations aren't always so ideal. Sometimes "you" aren't in control - of source code or version control, of process, of update schedules, etc., etc, etc.  Take your "you're doing it wrong" and say that when you are working on someone else's code base that has never heard of source control with a client that's 18 versions behind on an ancient version of Windows in a quarantined environment and things can't break.  In an ideal situation, if patching is easier, than perhaps if a single person is in complete control of everything they maybe did something wrong.

Comment: As I said, you're doing something wrong. If you don't have source control, you're doing it wrong, there really isn't more for me to say.

Comment: right .. it would seem you have never worked in the real world, or on any project not 100% under your complete control.

Comment: You still don't understand what I'm saying here. I am not saying you can do it differently under those circumstances. All I am saying is that it is still the wrong way. If all you got is a hammer, and you need to "saw" off a piece of wood, yes, you can do it with the hammer, and since that is all you have, that is the solution you have to pick. It is, however, *still the wrong way*. If you come asking for advice, I will tell you what the right way is. If you can't do that, it doesn't make it any less right, but it might not be an option for you. That is why my comment is just that, a comment.

Answer (score 4):

You could disassemble the DLL you have using ildasm.exe, then fix the code, and then reassemble with ilasm.exe.  This is some pretty advanced stuff though... I tried it in the past and had some success.